# How can i find roots about complex numbers $(z-2-i)^5=-1$ when $z=x+yi$

Tags: complex-numbers

So how can i solve the equation $(z-2-i)^4=-1$ when $z=x+yi$ and I need to find all the complex numbers as roots.

So can you please tell me how to solve that equation?

Is it like $\big((x-2)+i(y-1)\big)^4=-1$ and whats next?

Comment: This is like $z^5=-1$.

Comment: Here is a [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/144766) tutorial, it makes questions more readable.

Comment: Which one is it $(...)^4$ or $(...)^5$?

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have:

$$\left(\text{z}-2-i\right)^4=-1\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{z}-2-i=\left|-1\right|e^{\left(\arg\left(-1\right)+2\pi\text{k}\right)i}\tag1$$

Where $0\le\arg\left(-1\right)=\pi<2\pi$ and $\text{k}:0-3$

So, we get:

$$\text{z}=\left|-1\right|e^{\left(\arg\left(-1\right)+2\pi\text{k}\right)i}+2+i\tag2$$

The solutions are:

- $$\text{z}_0=\left|-1\right|e^{\left(\arg\left(-1\right)+2\pi\cdot0\right)i}+2+i\tag3$$
- $$\text{z}_1=\left|-1\right|e^{\left(\arg\left(-1\right)+2\pi\cdot1\right)i}+2+i\tag4$$
- $$\text{z}_2=\left|-1\right|e^{\left(\arg\left(-1\right)+2\pi\cdot2\right)i}+2+i\tag5$$
- $$\text{z}_3=\left|-1\right|e^{\left(\arg\left(-1\right)+2\pi\cdot3\right)i}+2+i\tag6$$

Comment: sorry my potency was wrong so the right is ^4. so how can i add my z=x+yi to your solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $u_k, k \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ are the five different solutions of $u^5=-1$, than the solutions of your equations are $z_k=u_k+i+2$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:)**
$$w^4=-1=\cos(\pi+2k\pi)+i\sin(\pi+2k\pi)$$
with [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula):
$$w=\cos(\dfrac{\pi+2k\pi}{4})+i\sin(\dfrac{\pi+2k\pi}{4})$$
for $k=0,1,2,3$. then replace $w=z-2-i$.